# How do I add background color to just the width of centred text?

Tags: css, text, background, inline, center

I imagine this is straight forward, but I haven't been able to work out how to do it.  I would like to center some text in a div, and then apply a background color to just the width of the text, without having to enter a width for the div (so that the background color is automatically the width of the text)

At the moment my CSS looks like this:

```
.heading {
text-align: center;
background-color:red;
}
```

which centers the text, but makes the background of the entire line on the page red.

When I add `display:inline` the background is just the width of the text, but the text is no longer centred.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your text inside .heading in a span and then:

```
.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading span {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for also! :D

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to achieve this with one DIV only. You may need to enclose text into SPAN and apply background color to it. For example HTML code will look like:

```
<div class="heading"><span>Sample Text</span></div>
```

And CSS code will look like:

```
DIV.heading { text-align: center; }
DIV.heading SPAN { background-color: red; }
```